# Excel-VBA: Check how many items have been selected in a column filter (or limit selections)

Tags: vba, excel, filter, autofilter

I need to control a simple **auto filter on a column** on an Excel sheet.

After researching this it seems that there is no specific event fired when such a filter is changed. So the only event that comes to mind here is the `.Calculate` event but I am not sure that's reliable here.

As an alternative, is there a way to count how many items in a specific filter have been selected ?
In my case I just need to capture **if more than 1 items have been selected** in the filter (but not all).
Since it seems I cannot prevent or limit this I would then **at least like to show a warning message**.

Can someone help me with this ?

**My filter data:**

```
Worksheets(1).Range("$C$1:$C$100").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: use `=subtotal(103, $C$2:$C$100)` If no values are showing the count will be zero; otherwise the numerical count of visible values.

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks but this doesn't help me as in my case the same value can appear multiple times in this column. I need to know if there have been more than 1 items selected in the filter dropdown (if I cannot prevent this).

Comment: Then use aggregate instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

You can select some items like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$23").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Belinda", "Cordelia", "Darth Vader"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Once the items have been selected by either the macro or manually, you can display the number of selected numbers with:

```
Sub HowMany()
    MsgBox UBound(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).Criteria1)
End Sub
```

[image]

Of course there may be many more rows displayed if the values appear more than once in the column.

Comment: Thanks so much ! This is awesome and works great - exactly what I was looking for. :)